# Write information on aux file when using include to build document

Tags: auxiliary-files

This may be an odd question, but I'm having trouble writing information on the main `.aux` file when I split my documents through more than one `.tex`.

Here is the deal: I'm trying to calculate the size of the widest TOC label so that I can align all chapter/section names in the TOC based on this measure. Someone has already told me how to do this measuring, but I need to write this info in the `.aux` file so that in the first pass I calculate the size and in the second pass I make use of it.

What is troubling me is that the command that I'm using is not working, and I believe the reason is the said modularization of the document, since when I try it in a single-file document it works ok.

Here is the part of the code that should write the info:

```
\AtEndDocument{
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
    {\string\global\string\setlength{\string\widesttoclabel}{\the\widesttoclabel}}
}
```

With `\widesttoclabel` being the macro that holds the length I've calculated.

But when I check the `.aux` file, that entry is not anywhere around, neither in the "master document's" aux nor in the others'.

Am I missing something?

**OBS**: I know I could workaround and replace `\include`s with `\input`s, but this would be terrible, since my document has very many pages... So this shouldn't be an option if I could choose.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When LaTeX executes `\end{document}`,

1. it calls the hook for the collected stuff in `\AtEndDocument`,
2. `\clearpage is called and
3. the main `.aux` file is closed.

You are using `\protected@write` that is a deferred writing. It puts a write node in the output that is executed (actually written), when the page is output.
However, if at the end of document the latest page is already output, nothing happens, because TeX does not create a page, if it only contains a write node.
Therefore you need `\immediate\write`.

The order of the end of document hook is the order of `\AtEndDocument` calls. Thus the writing to the `.aux` file might come too early, if a section with a longer title is added via `\AtEndDocument`. Package `atveryend` provides the hook command `\AfterLastShipout` that is called after the `\AtEndDocument` hook (1.) and after the final `\clearpage` (2.) before the `.aux` file is closed (3.).

Thus the code example becomes:

```
\usepackage{atveryend}
\newdimen\widesttoclabel
\setlength{\widesttoclabel}{0pt}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xdef\thewidesttoclabel{\the\widesttoclabel}%
}%
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \global\string\widesttoclabel=\the\widesttoclabel\relax
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
% ...
\begin{document}
  % Macro \thewidesttoclabel contains the width of the widest toc label
  % from the previous run. Dimen register \widesttoclabel is initially 0pt
  % and should be updated for each longer entry found during the document.
\end{document}
```

Further remarks:

- `\global\setlength` is not correct, because it depends on the implementation
  of macro `\setlength`. The documentation does not ensure that `\global` can be used to get a global assignment. In contrary, package `calc` redefines `\setlength`. Then a prefix `\global` fails.
  Correct variants:

  ```
  \setlength{\mylength}{...}%
  \global\mylength=\mylength
  ```

  or if in this case, there are not any calculations, thus we can use

  ```
  \global\widesttoclabel=\the\widesttoclabel\relax
  ```
- LaTeX provides `\nofiles` that disables the writing to auxiliary files.
  `\protected@write` is redefined accordingly. And it sets the switch `\if@filesw` that can be asked, whether auxiliary files are writable.
  Since the solutions uses `\immediate\write` directly, the writing is
  put between `\if@filesw` and `\fi` to respect `\nofiles`.

### Variant

The following is a variant that uses a global macro definition `\xdef` rather than a global assignment in the `.aux` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{atveryend}

% Dimen register \widesttoclabel is used for measuring and
% finding the maximal value that is written to the `.aux` file
% at the end of document.
\newdimen\widesttoclabel
\setlength{\widesttoclabel}{0pt}

% \thewidesttoclabel is a macro with the width of the
% widest toc label. It is defined in the `.aux` file.
% In the first run, the dummy value 0pt is used.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand*{\thewidesttoclabel}{0pt}%
}

\makeatletter
% \set@widesttoclabel is used at the end of the main .aux file
\newcommand*{\set@widesttoclabel}[1]{%
  \xdef\thewidesttoclabel{#1}%
}
\AfterLastShipout{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{%
      \xdef\string\thewidesttoclabel{\the\widesttoclabel}%
    }%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
Widest entry: \thewidesttoclabel
\settowidth{\widesttoclabel}{Hello World}% dummy
\end{document}
```