# Size of subfigure fitting its content (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

How can I set the width of a `subfigure` to fit its content, i. e. a `tikzpicture`.

In my MWE I do not want to specify `0.1\textwidth` respectively `0.9\textwidth`, but instead I want the whitespace to be distributed equally around both subfigures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.1\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (pd1) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (b) at (0,0) {b};
\node[draw] (c) at (5,0) {c};

\draw (b) to (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I found this answer [How can I access the size of a tikzpicture's bounding box outside the tikzpicture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137356/how-can-i-access-the-size-of-a-tikzpictures-bounding-box-outside-the-tikzpictur/137367#137367) but didn't read it in detail until now. I was wondering if my aim could be achieved easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could place the `tikzpicture` in a `\savebox` and measure its size. This size can then be used for the `subfigure`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newsavebox{\myboxb}
\newlength{\mylengthb}

\newsavebox{\myboxa}
\newlength{\mylengtha}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\myboxa}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (pd1) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\settowidth{\mylengtha}{\usebox{\myboxa}}

\savebox{\myboxb}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (b) at (0,0) {b};
\node[draw] (c) at (5,0) {c};

\draw (b) to (c);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\settowidth{\mylengthb}{\usebox{\myboxb}}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\mbox{}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\mylengtha}
\usebox{\myboxa}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\mylengthb}
\usebox{\myboxb}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill
\mbox{}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(Thanks to @marmot for spotting the issue about the `\hfill` between the images and the boarders)

Comment: @marmot Thanks for noticing this! I just changed the code a bit and included something similar

Answer (score 4):

I think that @samcarter's nice proposal is the way to go. This is only if you need to access the nodes later (with `remember picture`), in which case `\savebox`es may be inconvenient. This proposal measures the widths of the `tikzpicture`s and writes them to the aux files such that they get used in the next run. Conceptually it is the same as e.g. [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116008/121799).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\ifdefined\figwidthA
\else
\xdef\figwidthA{2cm}
\fi
\ifdefined\figwidthB
\else
\xdef\figwidthB{2cm}
\fi
\tikzset{save tikzpic width in/.style={execute at end picture={
\path let \p1=($(current bounding box.east)-(current bounding box.west)$)
in \pgfextra{\xdef#1{\x1}};}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\figwidthA}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[save tikzpic width in=\figwidthA]
\node[draw] (pd1) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{\figwidthB}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[save tikzpic width in=\figwidthB]
\node[draw] (b) at (0,0) {b};
\node[draw] (c) at (5,0) {c};

\draw (b) to (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill{\vphantom{x}}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\makeatletter 
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figwidthA{\figwidthA}\relax} 
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figwidthB{\figwidthB}\relax} 
\makeatother 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you use `{` brackets `}` around `vphantom`?

Comment: @Ben No. It is a relic of something else I tried.